# SQL check if time occurs between certain time slots

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of appointments (see below)

```
ID | Start Time | End Time |
1  | 09:00      | 09:45    |
2  | 10:15      | 10:30    |
```

What I want to do is to have output a table that shows if each record occupies a 15 minute time slot. So the table above would output like this:

```
09:00 - 09:15 | 09:16 - 09:30 | 09:31 - 09:45 | 09:46 - 10:00 | 10:01 - 10:15 | 10:16 - 10:30
ID 1          | ID 1          | ID 1          |               | ID 2          | ID 2
```

Any ideas of where to even start with this?!

**EDIT:**

This is where I'm going with this, just not attempted to include end times or how a timeslot that is spanned by the start and end time like ID 1 in the example at 09:16 - 09:30:

```
SELECT 
'09:00 - 09:15' = case when 
cast(a_start as time) >= '09:00:00' and cast(a_start as time) < '09:16:00'
then a_id else '' END,

'09:16 - 09:30' = case when 
cast(a_start as time) >= '09:16:00' and cast(a_start as time) < '09:30:00'
then a_id else '' END,

'09:31 - 09:45' = case when 
cast(a_start as time) >= '09:31:00' and cast(a_start as time) < '09:45:00'
then a_id else '' END,     

'09:46 - 10:00' = case when 
cast(a_start as time) >= '09:46:00' and cast(a_start as time) < '10:00:00'
then a_idelse '' END 

  FROM appointments
```

EDIT 2:

Now kind of working:

```
SELECT 

    '08:00 - 08:59' = case when 
    (cast(a_start as time) <= '08:00:00') 
    AND 
    (cast(a_end as time) >= '08:59:00')
    then a_id else '' END,

    '09:00 - 09:15' = case when 
    (cast(a_start as time) <= '09:00:00') 
    AND 
    (cast(a_end as time) >= '09:15:00')
    then a_id else '' END,

    '09:16 - 09:30' = case when 
    (cast(a_start as time) <= '09:16:00') 
    AND 
    (cast(a_end as time) >= '09:30:00')
    then a_id else '' END,

    '09:31 - 09:45' = case when 
    (cast(a_start as time) <= '09:31:00') 
    AND 
    (cast(a_end as time) >= '09:45:00')
    then a_id else '' END,     

    '09:46 - 10:00' = case when 
    (cast(a_start as time) <= '09:46:00') 
    AND 
    (cast(a_end as time) >= '10:00:00')
    then a_id else '' END,

    '10:01 - 10:15' = case when 
    (cast(a_start as time) <= '10:01:00') 
    AND 
    (cast(a_end as time) >= '10:15:00')
    then a_id else '' END 


      FROM appointments
```

Comment: Does this mean the appointment needs to be entirely within the timeslot (which means an appointment can belong to only one timeslot) - or overlaps it in any way (in which case an appointment can be in multiple timeslots).

Comment: No an appointment could potentially overlap like the example above. It could also have an appointment that starts or ends at say 09:03. If the start or end appears within the timeslot I want it to return the ID of the record to show that the slot is occupied. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Your time slots are a little odd here. The first time slot starts at 9 but the next one is at 9:16 and the last one ends at 10:30. The first slot has 15 minutes and the rest of them have only 14 minutes. Do you have second recorded in your data? If so how do you want to handle the gaps in your time? Also, do you know what time slots you may need covered (with NULL when no data) or do you need to dynamically determine the number of columns?

Comment: First, create a table (temp-table?) of all the start time of the time slot (9:01, 9:16, ...). Second, matching ID of these start time with the slots. (Starttimeslot between start-time and end-time). Third, pivot.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes sorry about that, the time slots could be any length really, that doesn't matter. Number of columns will be fixed. Should be same length timeslots throughout each day - I think that is what you meant?

Comment: Done, see above :)

Comment: What happens when you have overlapping appointments? How do you want that returned?

Comment: In theory there should be no overlapping appointments so would not need to handle that thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a dynamic pivot.

I cheated a bit by dropping the temp results into a #temp, but this can be changed if necessary.  I also added a DATE as the first column (easily removed)

```
--Drop Table #Temp

Declare @TimeR1 time = '09:00'
Declare @TimeR2 time = '17:00'

Select Date = cast([Start Time] as date)
      ,Val  = concat('ID ',B.ID)
      ,Col  = Format(cast(A.TR1 as datetime),'HH:mm') +' - ' + Format(cast(A.TR2 as datetime),'HH:mm')
Into  #Temp
From (Select Top 96 
             TR1=cast(DateAdd(MINUTE,(15*(Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select null))-1))+1,'1900-01-01') as time)
            ,TR2=cast(DateAdd(MINUTE,(15*(Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select null))+0))+0,'1900-01-01') as time)
      From master..spt_values 
     ) A
Left Join YourTable B 
  on TR1 between cast([Start Time] as time)  and cast([End Time] as time) or TR2 between cast([Start Time ] as time) and cast([End Time] as time)
Where TR1 >=@TimeR1 and TR1<@TimeR2


Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(Col) From #Temp  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select [Date],' + @SQL + '
From (Select * From #Temp Where Date is not null
      Union All
      Select Date,Val,Col
        From (Select Distinct Date,Val='''' from #Temp Where Date is not Null) A
        Cross Join (Select Distinct Col From #Temp) B
) A
Pivot (max(Val) For [Col] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns
[image]

** Image is trucated... it actuall goes out to 17:00

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some date math and a cross tab (aka conditional aggregation). I also used a tally to generate the time slots based on the data that is in your table. You could adjust this as needed. Personally I keep a tally table as a view in my system. It is super crazy fast with zero reads.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
```

Now we need actual ddl to work with.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Appt') is not null
    drop table #Appt

create table #Appt
(
    ID int
    , StartTime time
    , EndTime time
)
insert #Appt select 1, '09:00', '09:45';
insert #Appt select 2, '10:15', '10:30';
```

To actually solve the problem I first generate the time slots, then I join your appointment data to the time slots to determine which appointment (if any) would be assigned to that time slot.

This will probably need a little tweaking to meet your exact requirements but this should be pretty close.

```
with TimeSlots as
(
    select TimeSlot = dateadd(minute, (t.N) * 15, '09:00') --should make the start time dynamic
    from cteTally t
    where t.N <=
    (
        select datediff(minute, MIN(StartTime), MAX(EndTime)) / 15
        from #Appt
    )
)
, Appointments as
(
    select *
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(order by ts.TimeSlot) as RowNum
    from TimeSlots ts
    left join #Appt a on convert(datetime, ts.TimeSlot) >= convert(datetime, a.StartTime) 
        AND convert(datetime, ts.TimeSlot) <= convert(datetime, a.EndTime)
)

select MAX(case when RowNum = 1 then ID end) as '09:00 - 09:15'
    , MAX(case when RowNum = 2 then ID end) as '09:16 - 09:30'
    , MAX(case when RowNum = 3 then ID end) as '09:31 - 09:45'
    , MAX(case when RowNum = 4 then ID end) as '09:46 - 10:00'
    , MAX(case when RowNum = 5 then ID end) as '10:01 - 10:15'
    , MAX(case when RowNum = 6 then ID end) as '10:16 - 10:30'
from Appointments
```